# Comparison of Icons

Tags: java

I am trying to do the game called TicTacToe but now I am stopped on one point:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    if (player==true){
        jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("x2.png"));
        player=false;
    } else {
        jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("o2.png"));
        player=true;
    }

    if (this.jButton1.getIcon()==this.jButton2.getIcon()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Win!");
    }
}
```

I have done this for all buttons.

When I have these three buttons with the same icon, the message does not appear. Why?

Comment: Without seeing more code I can only speculate that the icons you are retrieving may be the same picture, but they're probably instantiated as separate objects (using new), meaning they are not equal.

Comment: Needs more code, but my guess is you're comparing references instead of the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the difference of `==` and `equals`. I quess you have different objects. And with `==` you check if its the same object. You should have a "player variable" which you should compare.
Implement a method `jButton1.getTeamName()` and compare that values.

Comment: Your updated question clearly shows that its two different objects. You should probably track who clicked where in an extra array or so.

Comment: so you mean I have to create an array and attach every button to this array?

Comment: No. You should track which button is pressed by which player.